# Reading ListView from BackgroundWorker

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, listview, backgroundworker

I've tried doing some searchs but for the life of me I don't seem to be able to find the answer, or a suggested solution that works. Its probably my understanding, but hopefully asking my own question will give me an answer that works :o)

I have a Windows Form Application which consists of one item, ListView1

This ListView has items added to it from a file via a Drag / Drop which is done on the main UI Thread, no background worker, it consists of around 1500 rows.

I'm trying to get a background worker now to read this ListView, but I'm getting a Cross Threading error as ListView1 was not created on the same thread.

The error comes on the simplest of pieces of code, but I don't seem to be able to think of a way around it or implementing an invoke etc.

```
    For i = 0 To Me.ListView1.Items.Count - 1

        ValueStatement = ValueStatement & "(" & Me.ListView1.Items(i).SubItems(0).Text

        If i = Me.ListView1.Items.Count - 1 Or counter = 500 Then
            CommaTerminate = ";"
        Else
            CommaTerminate = ","
        End If


        For y = 0 To Me.ListView1.Columns.Count - 1
            ValueStatement = ValueStatement & "'" & Me.ListView1.Items(i).SubItems(y).Text & "'"
            If y = Me.ListView1.Columns.Count - 1 Then
                ValueStatement = ValueStatement & ")"
            Else
                ValueStatement = ValueStatement & ","
            End If

        Next
        ValueStatement = ValueStatement & CommaTerminate & vbNewLine


        If counter = 500 Then
            SQLStatement = "INSERT INTO RAW_CLI_DATA_" & GlobalVariables.CDR_Company & " VALUES " & vbNewLine & ValueStatement
            GenericDatabaseRequest(SQLStatement, "Loading RAW table with data..")
            counter = 0
            ValueStatement = ""
        End If

        counter = counter + 1
    Next
```

The error comes on the line `ValueStatement = ValueStatement & "(" & Me.ListView1.Items(i).SubItems(0).Text`

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Why are you using a `BackgroundWorker` ? Are you trying to read the items as they are loading?

Comment: I'm trying to make it so it doesn't lock the UI when reading the data as it then will place it into a Database in the background. I'm wanting the UI to display a loading icon so the end user knows something is happening.

Comment: So you want to do the IO operation on the background thread and progressively update the ListView as it processes the file content? I ask, because, in your example code you are trying to run code on the foreground thread building a string - it's not clear why you are doing that.

Comment: I have the code to populate the ListView on a background thread (which I'm not doing fyi), but this problem is just reading the data that is within the ListView. I'm building a Statement which will result in an SQL Statement later in the process, but the main issue isn't the building of a string, its the `For Each ListItem...`

Comment: Are you using the `ReportProgress` method? Then handle the `ProgressChanged` event to update the UI. You might post more of your code in order to get more assistance....

Comment: You cannot access controls from a BGW.  The point of a BackGroundWorker is to do some long running task in the background wihout locking up the UI.  What you can do is - perhaps - use the ReportProgrgress event to let the main UI thread update the ListView

Comment: @Plutonix - I'm not wanting to update the ListView, I'm wanting to take data from the ListView thats already there.

Comment: @Robin - I'll post the remainder of the code in a second

Comment: Use a DataGridView bound to a datatable.  You can access the actual data on another thread easily,

Comment: @Robin - Updated with slightly different code, using a For i = 0 to ... Basics are the same, when referencing the ListView "Text" I get the cross threading. I kind of understand why it happens, but would like to get to the data in the ListView via a background thread as it will be a complex process of manipulating the data and writing to a database. The only problem is the Reading from ListView, the remainder works as a Background Task

Comment: Not for nothing, but *creating* the data for 7500 rows plus inserting then into Access (no idea what DB you are using) via a DataTable took 8 seconds.  That is not really enough to justify a BGW, maybe a marquee ProgressBar.

Comment: @Plutonix - I am using SQLite. Can you share your code please, just so I can see if its a better solution to what I have

Comment: The relevant part is real simple: `myDA.Update(myDT)`.  Using a DGV and Datatable when the user adds data to the control, it is also added to the underlying Datatable.  When desired, just update the DataTable.  No need to create and concat SQL, no need to iterate Items and SubItems, no need to convert from string to other datatypes.  I would have thought SQLite was faster than Access at this, but it isnt: 50 secs for 3500 rows (including *creating* the fake data).  At that point I might update more incrementally.

Comment: @Plutonix - Can you share code? I have to admit I've not used a DataTable in vb.net before

Comment: Not really: I cant post a DB/DT/DA/DGV answer to a question about ListViews and Background workers.  It is basically an XY question: Your db updates seem slow (probably are - surprises me that OleDB is so much faster) thats the X.  So you think the answer is Y, use a BGW.  The real answer is to use the right objects and optimize the code.  BTW, using a transaction I got the insert time for 3500 rows down to 30secs.

Comment: **Now** we are cooking with fire!  Create 7500 new rows plus  insert them in 730 to 970 ms.  If you want to get the newly inserted Ids back, 1089 ms total.  There are multiple ways to insert, but I think I missed something  when I tried to just redirected the code to SQLite from Access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you went down the wrong road early on.  The `ListView` is supremely illsuited for database ops:

- Everything is contained as `String` which means somewhere you will have code to convert it to other types
- It does not support databinding which means you have to manually create rows...
- ... then later iterate them to fish the data back out.

A `DataGridView` and `DataTable` would be simpler: When the user enters data into the control and it would be stored in the table and as the proper type.  Setting the `DataTable` as the `Datasource`, the `DataGridView` would create the display (rows and columns) for you.

Some of the time it takes will be consumed by SQLite to perform the INSERT, but it also looks like you are spending a lot of time iterating and concatenating SQL.  It's usually better to work with the data than the user's View of it anyway, so extract and pass the data to the worker.

First, suck the data out of the `ListView` into a `String()()` container:

```
Dim data = lv.Items.
    Cast(Of ListViewItem).
    Select(Function(s) New String() {s.SubItems(0).Text,
                                     s.SubItems(1).Text,
                                     s.SubItems(2).Text}).
        ToArray()
```

Then pass it to the `BackGroundWorker`:

```
bgw.RunWorkerAsync(data)
```

The `DoWork` Event:

```
Private Sub bgw_DoWork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles bgw.DoWork

    ' unbox the data
    Dim dataToInsert = CType(e.Argument, String()())

    For n As Int32 = 0 To 2
        Console.WriteLine("[{0}], [{1}], [{2}]", dataToInsert(n)(0),
                          dataToInsert(n)(1),
                          dataToInsert(n)(2))
    Next

End Sub
```

Results:

> [Patient Tempest], [Lorem ipsum dolor sit], [Swordfish]
>   [Sour Priestess], [hendrerit nibh tempor], [Perch]
>   [Frozen Justice], [Interdum ex felis], [Swordfish]

It correctly prints the random data I put into the LV.

This will allow you to process the `ListView` Data in the `BackGroundWorker` but it wont really save any time, it just keeps the UI unlocked.  The real problem is elsewhere, probably in the DB ops.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to start looking at the DataSet that you mentioned in the original post as I can see the advantages to it in the long run, especially as more data will be loaded eventually and a ListView can only hold so many rows. Appreciate the help, luckily I hadn't wasted a day as I went down a similar road to the solution you posted to get round the issue.